# parse parenthesized numbers to negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can i Parse parenthesized numbers in a list of strings  to negative numbers (or strings with negative sign).

example

```
input  
list1= ['abcd','(1,234)','Level-2 (2):','(31)%', 'others','(3,102.2)%']  

output  
['abcd',-1234,'Level-2 (2):','-31%', 'others','-3102.2%']
```

strings only with numbers inside parenthesis or numbers with comma/dot inside parenthesis followed by a percentage(%) sign, should be parsed . other strings such as `'Level-2 (2):'` should not be parsed.

I have tried

```
translator = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('(),'))
['-'+(x.translate(translator)) for x in list1]
```

but the output is (every element has a `-` appended)

```
['-abcd', '-1234', '-Level-2 2:', '-31%', '-others', '-3102.2%']
```

Comment: Any reason that `Level-2 (2)` doesn't become `Level-2 -2` ?

Comment: @JonClements, those strings are references to some levels , not actual negative numbers

Comment: Okay... but how's the parser supposed to know that... it can't just take numbers between parentheses then... - the rules need to be better defined... Under what circumstance is something `(number)` allowed to become `-number` and when isn't it?

Comment: Also how did (1,234) change to -123?

Comment: @Devesh typo I guess... same as `(31.2)%` has become `-3102.2%` :)

Comment: sorry, corrected the input/output. @JonClements only negative numbers / percentages should be parsed , i.e. `a(2)` should remain `a(2)` and `(32)` should be `-32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `re.sub`, eg:

```
import re

list1 = ['abcd','(1,234)','Level-2 (2):','(31)%', 'others','(3,102.2)%']
res = [re.sub(r'^\(([\d+.,]+)\)(%?)$', r'-\1\2', el) for el in list1] 
# ['abcd', '-1,234', 'Level-2 (2):', '-31%', 'others', '-3,102.2%']
```

Comment: how can i remove the comas also

Comment: @Shijith if you're not going to have genuine commas in other strings, then you can just add `.replace(',', '')` to the lhs of the list-comp otherwise... you probably only want to apply it to strings that have changed.

Comment: @ jonClements thanks , but this fails for `Level-2, (2):`

Comment: got it with a slight change in my original code 
`translator = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('(),'))   
['-'+(x.translate(translator)) if re.match(r'^\(([\d+.,]+)\)(%?)$', x) else x for x in list1]`. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try using `re.match`

**Ex:**

```
import re

list1= ['abcd','(1,234)','Level-2 (2):','(31)%', 'others','(31.2)%']  
result = []
for i in list1:
    m = re.match(r"\((\d+[.,]?\d*)\)(%?)", i) 
    if m:
        result.append("-" + m.group(1)+m.group(2))
    else:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['abcd', '-1,234', 'Level-2 (2):', '-31%', 'others', '-31.2%']
```

---

*Update as per comment*

```
import re

list1 = ['abcd','(1,234)','Level-2 (2):','(31)%', 'others','(3,102.2)%']  
result = []
for i in list1:
    m = re.match(r"\((\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\)(%?)", i) 
    if m:
        result.append("-" + m.group(1).replace(",", "")+m.group(2))
    else:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['abcd', '-1234', 'Level-2 (2):', '-31%', 'others', '-3102.2%']
```

Comment: this fails for `(3,102.2)%`

Comment: Oh..did not see the new edit in the question..Updated ans

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to convert the value to int or float, `re.match` and `str.translate` should do the trick:

```
rx = re.compile('\([\d,.]+\)%?$')
tab = str.maketrans({i: None for i in '(),'})

output = ['-' + i.translate(tab) if rx.match(i) else i for i in list1]
```

It gives:

```
['abcd', '-1234', 'Level-2 (2):', '-31%', 'others', '-3102.2%']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list1:
    idx = list1.index(item)
    list1[idx] = '-' + list1[idx].replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','')

print (list1)
```

output:

```
['-abcd', '-1234', '-Level-2 2:', '-31%', '-others', '-3102.2%']
```

or just:

```
list1= ['abcd','(1,234)','Level-2 (2):','(31)%', 'others','(3,102.2)%']

print (['-' + item.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','') for item in list1])
```

output:

```
['-abcd', '-1234', '-Level-2 2:', '-31%', '-others', '-3102.2%']
```

Comment: `Level-2 (2):` should not be changed. only the actual negative numbers or negative percentages should be parsed.